# How can I make some row values NA if other is NA in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with three columns `Time`, observed value (`Obs.Value`), and an interpolated value (`Interp.Value`). If the value of `Obs.Value` is `NA` then the value of `Interp.Value` should also be `NA`. I can make the whole row `NA` but I need to keep the `Time` value.

Here is the repex:

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 10))
x <- c("Time", "Obs.Value", "Interp.Value")
colnames(dat) <- x
dat$Time <- seq(1,10,1)
dat$Obs.Value <- c(5,6,7,NA,NA,5,4,3,NA,2)
interp <- approx(dat$Time,dat$Obs.Value,dat$Time)
dat$Interp.Value <- round(interp$y,1)
```

Here is the code that makes the whole row `NA`

```
dat[with(dat, is.na(Obs.Value)|is.na("Interp.Value")),] <- NA
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
   Time Obs.Value Interp.Value
1     1         5            5
2     2         6            6
3     3         7            7
4     4        NA           NA
5     5        NA           NA
6     6         5            5
7     7         4            4
8     8         3            3
9     9        NA           NA
10   10         2            2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
dat$Interp.Value[is.na(dat$Obs.Value)] <- NA
dat
#    Time Obs.Value Interp.Value
# 1     1         5            5
# 2     2         6            6
# 3     3         7            7
# 4     4        NA           NA
# 5     5        NA           NA
# 6     6         5            5
# 7     7         4            4
# 8     8         3            3
# 9     9        NA           NA
# 10   10         2            2
```

Or if either column being `NA` is sufficient, then

```r
dat[!complete.cases(dat[,-1]),-1] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one column to change @r2evans' answer is pretty straightforward  and way to go. If there are more than one column that you want to change you can use `across` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(across(-c(Time,Obs.Value), ~replace(., is.na(Obs.Value), NA)))

#   Time Obs.Value Interp.Value
#1     1         5            5
#2     2         6            6
#3     3         7            7
#4     4        NA           NA
#5     5        NA           NA
#6     6         5            5
#7     7         4            4
#8     8         3            3
#9     9        NA           NA
#10   10         2            2
```